# What is wrong with the following scala code

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am getting the following compile time error in the code below

Error:(7, 29) not found: value Cons

def ::[B >: A](head: B) = Cons[B](head, this)

```
package basics

sealed trait List[+A] {

  import Types._

  def ::[B >: A](head: B) = Cons[B](head, this)

  def foreach(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
    this match {
      case x :: t => {
        f(x)
        t foreach f
      }
      case Nil => ()
    }
  }

}

object Types {
  type Cons[A] = ::[A]
}
case class ::[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
object Nil extends List[Nothing]


object Application {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    println("hello")

    3 :: Nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `Types.Cons`. You post wrong code btw. It is `::[B](head, this)` in your example.

Comment: @talex Will edit the code. Also Type.Cons has the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cons is a *type alias* not a value. It cannot occur on *value position*. For example:

I made a few modifications to your program to make it work:

```
case class ::[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
object Nil extends List[Nothing]

object Types {
  type Cons[A] = ::[A]
  def cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) = ::(head,tail)
}

sealed trait List[+A] {
  import Types._

  def ::[B >: A](head: B):Cons[B] = cons[B](head, this)
}
```

In `def ::[B >: A](head: B):Cons[B] = cons[B](head, this)`, `:Cons[B]` illustrates one correct use case of a type alias.

Another problem with your program is the existence of two `::` overloaded symbols in the same scope, that's why it required the creation of `Types.cons`, otherwise the Scala compiler thinks we are trying to invoke `List#::`

Here is a example from the REPL:

```
scala> 3 :: Nil
res0: Types.Cons[Int] = ::(3,Nil$@46fd71)

scala> 3 :: 4 :: Nil
res1: Types.Cons[Int] = ::(3,::(4,Nil$@46fd71))
```

See the type of the expressions is `Cons[Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that

```
object Types {
  type Cons[A] = ::[A]
}
```

is declaration of a type, but `Cons` in

```
def ::[B >: A](head: B) = Cons[B](head, this)
```

is reference to constructor. If you replace it with reference to actual constructor.

Add method `def Cons[A] = ::[A]` to `Types` and all will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative to defining `def Cons[A] = ::[A]` is `val Cons = ::`. This allows not just writing `Cons[B](head, this)`, but pattern matching

```
this match {
  case Cons(x, t) => ...
  case Nil => ...
}
```

and access to any other methods defined on the `::` companion object using `Cons` name. This is also what Scala standard library [does](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L94):

```
type Map[A, +B] = immutable.Map[A, B] 
type Set[A]     = immutable.Set[A] 
val Map         = immutable.Map 
val Set         = immutable.Set
```